# How to copy a file to multiple folders using the command line?

Tags: command-line, cp

I have tried to copy a file `test.txt` to multiple directories with one command:

```
cp ~/test.txt ~/folder1 ~/folder2
```

But I didn't succeed. Is there a way to do that in one command so I can copy a file or even a folder to multiple directories?

Comment: Not easily.  You may want to look into "rsync" for efficiently updating multiple existing copies of a folder

Comment: Try learning a bit of bash-script. It can get very useful: `for dest in folder1 folder2; do cp ~/test.txt ~/"$dest"; done`

Comment: Not a single command but might just help some people who stumble upon here: `cp ~/test.txt ~/folder1 && cp ~/test.txt ~/folder2`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/195972/2097284.

Comment: @ManuJärvinen comment may look flippant but it raises an important point.  Why complicate your script?  Two separate lines with a single copy is much more readable than all the other answers.  I have not used `tee` much so if I saw the accepted answer in a script, I would have no idea what it was doing.   I accept the answers are inventive but in a real world scenario you need simple.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`cp` can copy from multiple sources, but **can't** copy to multiple destinations. See `man cp` for more info.

The only bash command that I know which can copy/save to multiple destinations is `tee`.

You can use it in your case as follows:

```
tee ~/folder1/test.txt ~/folder2/test.txt < ~/test.txt
```

Note that `tee` also writes the input to the standard output (stdout). So if you don't want this, you can prevent it by redirecting standard output to `/dev/null` as follow:

```
tee ~/folder1/test.txt ~/folder2/test.txt < ~/test.txt >/dev/null
```

Comment: Clever, that's cheating! :)

Comment: @terdon Only if you consider that I/O redirection is an independent command :)

Comment: +1, clever! And if you use the `>/dev/null` works with binary files too, without messing up the terminal...

Comment: +1 for you , your always ma man :) , but what if i want to copy a directory ?

Comment: @nux Your question was about a file. The other answers which uses `cp` in combination with other commands are good in case if you want to copy a directory.

Comment: i will try answers and will report you the result , thanks man

Comment: @nux Don't forget to use `-r` option with `cp` in case of directories

Comment: @nux: `tee` unlike `cp` copies only file's content ignoring its mode, ownership, timestamps. To avoid repeating the filename: `f=text.txt; <~/$f tee ~/folder1/$f > ~/folder2/$f`

Comment: I love tee almost as much as coffee! ;-)

Comment: A way to avoid repeating the filename and the common part of the directory names, too!: `f=text.txt; tee ~/folder{1..2}/$f < ~/$f > /dev/null`

Comment: i just ran `tee packages/*/.npmrc < .npmrc` in a monorepo. you saved my life!

Comment: in `zsh` it truncated all files with `tee`.

Answer (score 78):

Another way to achieve a copy to multiple locations is the following command :

```
find dir1 dir2 -exec cp file.txt {} \;
```

If dir1 or dir2 have sub-directories that you don't want the file copied into, add
`-maxdepth 0`option :

```
find dir1 dir2 -maxdepth 0 -exec cp file.txt {} \;
```

Note that this will overwrite every file in `dir1` and `dir2` with `file.txt`'s contents, in addition to copying it. To only copy `file.txt` without affecting other files in these directories, tell `find` to only act on directories:

```
find dir1 dir2 -type d -exec cp file.txt {} \;
```

Comment: Nice solution! Seems to me more perfect than with tee.

Comment: Indeed, no redirection is involved and it's still one command.

Comment: @SylvainPineau In fact there are 3: one is `find` and for two times (in this case) `cp`. Not to say that `find` need a lot of time.

Comment: If the definition of a "command" is an "exec" call, maybe, but this is "one command" in my book.

Comment: technically two commands (find and cp) but no pipes so "looks" like one command ;-)

Comment: @SylvainPineau This will also create one copy of the file for every subdirectory in `dir1` and `dir2`.

Comment: @Henk, if dir1 or dir2 have subdirectory, adding `-maxdepth 0` to the find command will prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Correct. I already edited your answer. Enjoy!

Comment: I keep coming back to this one, so thought I should give an upvote :D

Comment: Does it do it parallely?

Comment: Wait, what? *"Note that this will overwrite every file in dir1 and dir2 with file.txt's contents"* -- Why does it do this? This is ***quite*** dangerous if you don't expect it to happen (which I wasn't, and almost messed up big time). Thanks for that note!  I would emphasise it even more just in case.

Answer (score 42):

The command

```
cp ~/test.txt ~/folder1 ~/folder2
```

tries to copy two files (`~/test.txt` and  `~/folder1`) to the destination `folder2`. (And if `~/folder2` exists and is a directory you will have an "omitting directory" warning).

If you want to make multiple copies of the file `test.txt`, you have to use a loop or multiple commands...

```
for i in ~/folder1 ~/folder2; do cp  ~/test.txt $i; done
```

(...and be careful if you have spaces embedded in the file names, you'll need quoting).

To copy whole directories you have to use the `-r` option:

```
for i in ~/folder1 ~/folder2; do cp -r ~/folder3 $i; done
```

this will create `~/folder1/folder3` and `~/folder2/folder3` with all the files included.

(*Learnt **8** years further down the line*: notice that you must be careful with spaces in file names. If you have them, change `$i` with `"$i"`, and be careful about quoting them).

Comment: For the passing reader: According to the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04), a for loop is a compound command. Therefore this is *still* one command, and meets all the requirements for the question.

Comment: @nux, I do not agree on the corrections. 1) the two capitals are wrong, my intent was to interleave the commands into the phrase. 2) the ellipsis is a matter of style; please let my style in.

Comment: ok , am sorry man ,  i thought it will look better .

Comment: on my system, it doesnt save folder3 as ~/folder1/folder3, but rather copies everything in folder3 into folder1

Answer (score 32):

You can create a help script , or you can do it with `xargs` and a print function (in this case, `echo` ):

```
echo firstDir secondDir | xargs -n 1 cp test
```

This will make each directory as an argument to the `cp` function , using **test** file as a parameter.

Comment: This is probably the best/most direct answer to the question

Answer (score 11):

After a long search this work like a Charm also !

```
for dir in *; do [ -d "$dir" ] && cp /path/file.txt "$dir" ; done
```

This will copy **file.txt** to every directory in your current location in terminal.

```
for dir in *; do [ -d "$dir" ] && cp -rf /path/folder "$dir" ; done
```

This will copy a folder to every sub directory in your current location in terminal.

I share it hope it helps others too .

Comment: In `zsh`, you can use `for i in *(/); ...` to loop over all the subdirectories, so you can avoid the `[ -d ...` test. Extended globbing is one of the reason I like it over `bash`.

Comment: can your right the code again in a command

Comment: In `zsh`, the first command of this answer can be simplified as `for dir in *(/); do cp /path/file.txt "$dir"; done`. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_2.html

Comment: You can eliminate the test in any Bourne derived shell with `for dir in */; `

Comment: @nux This works really well and the command is very easy to follow.  It should be voted much higher!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the file test.txt in every directory in /tmp/target/ ...

create a test environment:

```
mkdir /tmp/target
cd /tmp/target
mkdir -v {folder1,folder2,folder3}
touch test.txt
```

copy it:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec cp -vi test.txt {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought to give a variation to the answer of `Sylvain Pineau`

where `dir1` and `dir2` are not in your current directory.

`find ./ -maxdepth 2 -type d -name dir1 -exec cp file.txt {} \;`

here find will look for `dir1` two levels deep or you can leave out `-maxdepth` parameter to find `dir1` in all folders in current directory and below it.

Answer (score 0):

For files only without preserving attributes. Great if you're copying huge files and only want to read them once:

```
cat file1 >file2 >file3
```

For files or directories

```
xargs -n 1 cp file1 <<< 'file2 file3'
xargs -n 1 cp -r dir1 <<< 'dir2 dir3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to post html index files in the home directory of 10 newly created sub-domains. I created a file with the markup called `sites-index` and placed it in my working directory and another called `sites-home` that contained a list of full paths to the copied files on each line (eg `/var/path/to/site1/public_html/index.html`).

After a bit of searching here I lighted on the following bash script:

```bsh
while read file; do cp sites-index "$file"; done < sites-home
```

The script loops through the list, copies the html file at each iteration and sets each line in the list as the new path to which the html is copied.

To run in terminal, type `sudo -i` to start a root shell (enter your password when prompted). Execute the script.

Alternatively, you can save the command in a text file, for example `index.sh` and invoke it by typing at the terminal prompt, `sudo bash index.sh`.

If you run the script without `sudo` you'll see a list of the files that weren't created due to insufficient permission. If it executes correctly your files will be created without notice.

Comment: `cp` has a `--verbose` or `-v` flag which I find useful for scripts. One can also do a dry run with `echo` before the command ( `do echo cp ...`) and then remove the `echo` if the list is as expected, though running without `sudo` is also a convenient test for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`parallel cp foo {} ::: */` will copy `foo` to all the directories in the current directory in parallel:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir a 'b c'
$ touch foo
$ parallel cp foo {} ::: */
$ ls --recursive 
.:
 a  'b c'   foo

./a:
foo

'./b c':
foo
```

Useful if you want to do this quickly. Just remember that you need to quote the command or double-escape, for example:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir 'a b' 'c d' 'e f'
$ touch 'a b/foo'
$ parallel "cp 'a b/foo' {}" ::: 'c d' 'e f'
$ ls --recursive 
.:
'a b'  'c d'  'e f'

'./a b':
foo

'./c d':
foo

'./e f':
foo
```