# How to copy a certain file several times with a regular ending?

Tags: command-line, files, filemanager

I have a single file (a PDF) and I want to have lots of identical copies in the same folder (200 would be nice) named `file-001`, `file-002` etc.

How do I do it?

Comment: No, it is for error correction.

Comment: The _ is a typo I hope?

Comment: @Rinzwind yeah! that could be interesting - pick a random character for each? :p

Comment: @Tim: Well, to generate a random "_" or "-" you can `printf "%s\n" "$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '_-' | fold -w 1 | head -n 1 )"` :-P (and be warned that is a can of worms, because `echo -` is one of this corner cases...)

Comment: @Rmano I'll stick with `-` I think :P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do something like

```
< file tee file-{001..200}
```

however if the medium becomes unreadable it will not matter how many copies are on it - fundamentally backups require *diversity*.

Note that `tee` writes its standard input to standard output as well as to each of the given files - for large files, or for files containing binary data or other special characters that may interfere with your terminal settings, you will probably want to dump standard output to the bit bucket

```
< file > /dev/null tee file-{001..200}
```

Comment: `tee file-{001..200} < file >/dev/null` looks for me more legibly. See this almost duplicate answer: [How to copy a file to multiple folders in Terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/a/432818/147044)

Answer (score 22):

This is the classic case where shell tricks help a lot.

```
for i in {000..199}; do cp file file-$i; done
```

And **I know it's a joke**, but if you want a random  `_` or `-` separating the number from the name you can use:

```
for i in {000..199}; do 
    cp file file$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '_-' | fold -w 1 | head -n 1 )$i; 
done
```

(multiple line to help readability...)

:-P

Comment: What if I wanted every prime number to be a `_` and every non prime to be `-`? 1  is not prime, and you pick for 0! :P Jokes!

Answer (score 7):

To make a single duplicate of a file you probably know that you can use `cp`:

```
cp file file-001
```

Now, to make more duplicates to a file, you can combine `cp` with `xargs`. In your case:

```
echo file-{001..200} | xargs -n 1 cp file
```

will copy `file` to `file-001`, `file-002`,... ,`file-200`. See `man xargs` for more info.

Answer (score 4):

As always, the python truck comes late, but:

make it executable, drag it over a terminal window, drag the file to copy over the terminal window and set the number of copies:

```
script file number_ofcopies
```

The number of leading zeros is set automatically, the files are named `file_001.pdf`, `file_002.pdf`, with the filenumbers placed *before* the extension.

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import shutil

orig = sys.argv[1]; n = sys.argv[2]; size = len(str(n)); out = (orig[:orig.rfind(".")], orig[orig.rfind("."):])
for item in [out[0]+"_"+(size-len(str(item)))*"0"+str(item)+out[1] for item in range(1, int(n)+1)]:
    shutil.copyfile(orig, item)
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried with python earlier, but didn't like the inelegance... I typically go for python :)

Comment: @Tim It must be the font of the code on this site that hinders the prettyness of the python code :)

Comment: There are several ways to make this.