# How can I add different files to multiple directories in one command?

Tags: fedora

I need to add one  file to about 7 different directories. I'm using Fedora 24... I know I need to use the touch command but what parameters will I need?

Comment: `touch {dir1,dir2,...,dir7}/file`

Comment: Although the command works the same in Ubuntu, keep in mind this site is called AskUbuntu so you shouldn't use the word `Fedora` in your question.

Comment: @muru just post it as answer, why leave it as comment ?

Comment: Cody, just out of curiosity, why did you come Ubuntu site if you are using Fedora ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file to multiple folders using the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/432795/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-folders-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

Use brace expansion in bash:

```
touch {dir1,dir2,dir3,dir4,dir5,dir6,dir7}/file
```

If the directories are named after a pattern, you might even be able to generate that. For example, if the directories were actually named like on the command above:

```
touch dir{1..7}/file
```

Answer (score 2):

If directories are different use this:

```
touch {d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7}/file_name
```

Or you can use this one:

```
touch dir{1..7}/file_name
```

This command creates file in **dir1, dir2, ... dir7** respectively.